# Create directories with Ansible using two separate lists

Tags: list, multidimensional-array, ansible, nested-lists

I want to create a series of directory trees dependent on two seperate lists.

Example:

```
---
# variable file ...
datacenters:
  - london
  - paris
types: 
  - databases
  - baremetal
  - vms
```

So I want my trees to be like so ...

```
    dest: "/{{ datacenter.0 }}/{{ types.0 }}"
    dest: "/{{ datacenter.0 }}/{{ types.1 }}"
    dest: "/{{ datacenter.0 }}/{{ types.2 }}"
    dest: "/{{ datacenter.1 }}/{{ types.0 }}"
    dest: "/{{ datacenter.1 }}/{{ types.1 }}"
    dest: "/{{ datacenter.1 }}/{{ types.2 }}"
    dest: "/{{ datacenter.N }}/{{ types.N }} .... etc
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this without using an include file ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Nested Loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops)

```
- name: Test with_nested
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    datacenters:
      - london
      - paris
    types:
      - databases
      - baremetal
      - vms

  tasks:
   - name: Do it
     debug: msg="{{item[0]}}/{{item[1]}}"
     with_nested:
       - datacenters
       - types
```